# Backbone with or without RequireJS: What is better for data encapsulation?

Tags: oop, backbone.js, model-view-controller, requirejs, encapsulation

I am in the process of transitioning my 'regular' Backbone projects into a combination of Backbone and RequireJS. While this process works pretty flawless, I still have one question.

Previously I declared a global namespace for my app to which I then bound all my models, views an collections. This is a tip I actually got from the [Backbone ToDoMVC project](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/examples/backbone).

So for example, the `initialize` method of a view could look like this:

```
initialize: function () {
  app.employees = new app.EmployeeCollection();
  app.employees.fetch();
}
```

This works because at the beginning of every file, I've done this:

```
var app = app || {};
```

Now when defining my files as AMD modules, the `app` namespace doesn't exist anymore, which means everything is much more encapsulated:

```
initialize: function () {
  var employees = new EmployeeCollection();
  employees.fetch();
}
```

The `EmployeeCollection` is loaded with RequireJS:

```
var EmployeeCollection = require('collections/EmployeeCollection');
```

Unfortunately I am still very new to Backbone and MVC in general, so I am unsure if this is a good or a bad thing.

What impact will this have on my project – is it okay to use an app namespace like I did previously or does this break any MVC/OOP 'rule'? Are there any Backbone specific consequences I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, loading the EmployeeCollection via requirejs is a good thing.  This explicitly lists each module's dependencies and lets requirejs help you with loading modules in the proper order.

Both the app namespace approach and the requirejs approach are both valid.  Backbone won't care which approach you take since with either you have the necessary View/Collection/Model constructor available to use.  Personally I like the above benefits I mentioned of requirejs but it's a personal preference you'll have to decide.

However, you shouldn't use requirejs and an all-knowing app namespace together.  If you're committed to requirejs then you should only use the app namespace sparingly with top-level data that most of your app will need, rather than attaching all of your requirejs modules to it.

For example, you might use it for a global UserModel that contains information about the current user.  To do this you'd create an app object as a requirejs module just like you did with your EmployeeCollection, and then whatever module constructs the UserModel would require 'app' and do a simple assignment: app.user=user.

I said do this sparingly because using a global app namespaces for all your modules would sacrifice much of the benefit of requirejs and would cause you some sequencing pain.  Namely:

- You can no longer see the actual dependencies for each module declaratively and visualize easily how all your modules fit together.  Instead of having the initialize function of your view (or whatever that is) require in 'collections/EmployeeCollection' you'd be requiring 'app'; not a lot of context there.
- Requirejs will take care of loading required modules first before allowing your defining function to run.  But if everything just requires 'app' then requirejs will only ensure 'app' is defined first and you're on your own for everything else.  If app.Bar requires app.Foo, you have to do something to make sure app.Foo gets loaded and defined first.
- On a similar note, if requirejs can't figure out all your dependencies because everything just requires 'app' then requirejs's javascript concatenator and optimizer tool (called r.js) will be either useless to you or require a lot of maintenance to add all your modules to a list that it should compile.

If you decide to use requirejs, embrace what it can do for you and just require in the modules you want instead of relying heavily on a global namespace.  But there's not a right or wrong way choosing between these two approaches; each is used by lots of smart people.

Comment: Thanks, great answer! Helped a lot!